# How to pass one Vec to multiple functions in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust, ownership

I wrote a `max` function which takes a `Vec` as a parameter. It works as I expected. Then I added a `min` function the same as the `max` function:

```
fn main() {
    let my_array = vec![61, 14, 71, 23, 42, 8, 13, 66];
    let max = max(my_array);
    let min = min(my_array);
    println!("Max value is {}.", max);
}

fn max(array: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let mut max = array[0];
    for val in array {
        if max < val {
            max = val;
        }
    }
    max
}

fn min(array: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let mut min = array[0];
    for val in array {
        if min > val {
            min = val;
        }
    }
    min
}
```

Rust reports an error if I put the same `my_array` parameter on the call to `min`:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `my_array`
 --> src/main.rs:4:19
  |
2 |     let my_array = vec![61, 14, 71, 23, 42, 8, 13, 66];
  |         -------- move occurs because `my_array` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3 |     let max = max(my_array);
  |                   -------- value moved here
4 |     let min = min(my_array);
  |                   ^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

How can I write code that works?

Comment: You are most advised to read about [move semantics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ownership.html#move-semantics).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is an issue that very beginners to Rust will experience. As a beginner, you should read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/). A lot of effort has been put into this book, especially for newcomers to Rust. This will cover many things that you will run into.

Relevant sections:

- [Data Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-02-data-types.html)
- [Understanding Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html)
- [References and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html)

---

The underlying problem is that you've *transferred ownership* of the vector when you call `max`. The value is then gone; `main` no longer has it.

The simplest thing to to is to clone the vector before passing to `max`. This allows `main` to keep ownership of `my_array` and then transfer ownership to `min` on the subsequent line:

```
let max = max(my_array.clone());
let min = min(my_array);
```

This is inefficient, as neither `max` nor `min` need to take ownership of the vector to do their work. Cloning the `Vec` also requires additional memory allocation. It's more idiomatic to pass in a *slice*, which is a type of reference to the data inside the `Vec`:

```
let max = max(&my_array);
let min = min(&my_array);
```

```
fn max(array: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut max = array[0];
    for &val in array {
        if max < val {
            max = val;
        }
    }
    max
}
```

When iterating over a slice, you get back references to the items in the slice. With integers, we can dereference them (here using the `&` in `for &val in array`) and make a copy of the value.

See also:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

---

Even better, there's no need to rewrite basic functions like this. You also **assume there's always at least one value**, which isn't true for an empty vector. The idiomatic solution is to use [iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html):

```
fn main() {
    let my_array = vec![61, 14, 71, 23, 42, 8, 13, 66];
    let max = my_array.iter().max();
    let min = my_array.iter().min();
    println!("Max value is {:?}.", max);
    println!("Min value is {:?}.", min);
}
```

This uses [`Iterator::min`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min) and [`Iterator::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max), 
 which each return an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), as an empty slice has no minimum or maximum value.

Technically, it's a little different from your original solution, as `min` and `max` are `Option<&i32>`; a reference to the original slice. You can get back to `Option<i32>` by using [`Option::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied):

```
fn main() {
    let my_array = vec![61, 14, 71, 23, 42, 8, 13, 66];
    let max = my_array.iter().max().copied();
    let min = my_array.iter().min().copied();
    println!("Max value is {:?}.", max);
    println!("Min value is {:?}.", min);
}
```

---

Bonus information: slices, `Vec`s, and arrays are all different types. It's not correct to refer to `my_array` as an array at all.